# Set taxonomy fields on post with AJAX

Tags: custom-taxonomy, ajax

I'm working on a Movie site in WordPress and I'm developing a plugin to fill in fields on my custom post type from IMDb. I've created a search form meta box and using AJAX I can update the values of input and textarea fields because you can just set those with .val(newvalue). Is it possible to set/add custom taxonomy values, like Tags, as well? I'd like to be able to add values to my custom taxonomy 'Actors' as well but it doesn't appear to be a simple form field.

[image]

plugin.php

```
function imdb_ajax_action(){
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($data['imdb_ajax_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))){
        die(-1);
    }

    $api_meta = null;

    if ($data['imdb-box-title']){
        $search_title = $data['imdb-box-title'];
        $api_url = 'MY_API_URL';
        $api_response = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url));

        $api_meta = [
            'year' => $api_response->Year,
            'synopsis' => $api_response->Plot,
            'director' => $api_response->Director,
            'runtime' => $api_response->Runtime,
            'rating' => $api_response->imdbRating,
        ];
    }

    print json_encode($api_meta);
    wp_die();
}
```

imdb-ajax.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('body').on('click', '#scrape-imdb', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $me = $(this),
    action = 'imdb_ajax_action';

    var data = $.extend(true, $me.data(), {
     action: action,
     form_data: $('#post').serializeArray()
    });

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
      if (response == '0' || response == '-1'){
        console.error('IMDb AJAX error');
        console.log(response);
      } else {
        console.log('AJAX successful');
        var movie_data = $.parseJSON(response);

        $("div[data-name='year']").find('input').val(movie_data.year);
        $("div[data-name='synopsis']").find('textarea').val(movie_data.synopsis);
        $("div[data-name='director']").find('input').val(movie_data.director);
        $("div[data-name='runtime']").find('input').val(movie_data.runtime);
        $("div[data-name='imdb_rating']").find('input').val(movie_data.rating);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: The input for tags is fairly straightforward, you could add the actors, comma separated, to the `input` element, and then 'click' the Add button with jQuery, then WordPress will take care of actually adding/selecting the terms.

Comment: @JacobPeattie you're right, that works quite well. Thanks!